# CButton encapsulate button press event handling

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a problem that I imagine is fairly easy to solve but is one of those things you probably know or you don't - and I don't!

I have created a class inherited from a CButton, and as part of the construction of this new class I pass in a pointer to a callback function which I need to trigger when the button is pressed.

The trouble is that I can't find an appropriate event to use within the inheritied CButton class itself as even such as BN_CLICKED only seem to work if trapped on the inherited CButton class' parent window.

Any help massively appreciated. Thanks, Dave.

Comment: Have you tried `OnLButtonDown` and it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you have any prior experience with MFC? It sounds like you're trying to do something in a very non-standard way. Perhaps you're more experienced with .NET WinForms and trying to apply the same concepts? MFC is very different in this regard, and it's much easier to follow the idioms for the particular toolkit that you're using.

Comment: Thankyou for the comments - someone on another forum has given me the answer. I am relatively inexperienced with MFC having only used it for about 5 months - the problem I come across is that I know that something should work, but it's just having that fragment of information to make things work. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/211515/CButton-encapsulated-button-press-event-handling).

Answer (score 1):

Just try [OnLButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c293as9k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Not appropriate. A "click" is when button is down and then up. Just do it: Mouse down on a button, DONT mouse up, but move mouse away from button, and then do mouse-up. The button won't get this event!